# Is there a general method of drawing 2d objects on a digital screen

Tags: java, c, geometry, shapes, pixel

Some context, I want to draw 2D objects by defining a set of pixels to change to a color which represents the shape. For example, if I wanted to draw a square I'd define a top left corner say (0,0), and a bottom right corner say (10,10). Then I'd change the color of all the pixels x values 0-10 with y values 0-10.

Unfortunately I don't have a solid step by step method to complete this, and am only able to draw squares/rectangles due to how simple they are.

Is there a method you can describe, or a resource that describes how to do this you can point me to, which will help me draw shapes other then squares and rectangles?

pseudo code, or a basic implementation of this in C, or java would be very helpful. Also, just a thorough description of how this would be achieved would also be helpful.

Comment: There are an infinite number of shapes other than squares and rectangles.  Are you asking about circles? Ellipses?  N-gons? Rounded rectangles?  Stars?  Other shapes?  You're second year in CS and Physics... how did you get there by sleeping through high school geometry?  In any case, this question is much too broad for SO.

Comment: lol, probably. I was thinking just a few examples like say triangle, and circle. Because when you go to draw a circle you can't just use r^2 = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2, because you can't draw all the points by simply entering x values, because often you'll get a rational, or irrational number which will give error when drawing on a coordinate system based on integers

Comment: So... are you asking about how to round a float to an int?  Or maybe supersampling and antialiasing?

Comment: sort of, maybe I should have worded it differently. I am mostly interested in finding a method of taking an equation for a shape. Then putting it on the screen. Which would require a way of defining the bounds of the shape. without leaving gaps due to rounding error

Comment: Most engineering (CAD) or other serious applications - even gaming and 3D - keep the world model in some sort of real space coordinate system (ie: a continuous Euclidian space represented by floating point coordinates).  Only in the final rendering step are those coordinates mapped to the 2D canvas (and converted to integers).  Some sort of antialiasing algorithm is then applied to smooth the hard bounds created by the rasterizing process.  These are all big topics far too broad to address in an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I figured I'd check to see if the was an easy way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

Comment: I've actually read that article before, but I suppose a method one might use would be to calculate the positions of some nodes. Then draw a straight vector between each node. For example a circle you could calculate the number of nodes using numberOfNodes = (4)*2^n  with n representing the level of accuracy you want. Then calculate the position of each node using (h-r/n, k-r/n), with the +- signs changing based on what quadrant you're in. h=center x coord, and k=center y coord. Also, you'd need to use (h+-r, k+-r) for the transition points between the quadrants. The r only affects 1 for each

Comment: ran out of room, to clarify a bit for the last bit the left most node, which is a transition point between quadrants would be (h-r, k), and the next one at the top (h, k-r)....

Comment: Also, there'd be a tiny bit of rounding error, but it wouldn't cause gaps, because the position you start each vector on is whatever value you got after the rounding error, and this is the same for the ending point of the vector.

Comment: if you're interested. Check out my GitHub later. I am going to do a write up about this now. I was just thinking, you could extrapolate this method to be used for other shapes.

Comment: Well, to be honest, these are problems that have long since been solved with extreme efficiency.  Rather than leaping into the deep end with a crazy new idea, it's probably better to study the libraries that exist already to see what types of solutions are commonly in use.  It's a lot harder to improve on the status-quo if you don't really know what the status-quo is -- it's also much easier to go chasing after bad solutions if you're not aware of how good the current ones are.

Comment: This is true. I'll likely do it anyway as an exercise though, which will increase my understanding. Then for production purposes modify the code, or use a alternate method. Another interesting method I just thought of would be to start at the top of the circle draw a point. Then move down 1, and move out one in either direction and draw, and continue down until the distance between the two points being drawn = diameter. Then do the same thing down until the two points meet.

Comment: Look for `rasterization`. For example: polygon rasterization

Comment: That is actually perfect, thanks. A good topic to research.

Answer (score 0):

Like J... said there's a lot to cover, but I do like the method you described in the comments. I think the biggest challenge of using the method you have described would be creating the vectors between the nodes. A solution you could use to draw the vectors would be to stagger the pixels to create the illusion of a straight line. Also, shapes would become less jagged as you increased the value of n.